# Find discarded records postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query

`select count(id)filter(where id>2 and id<=50) from table;`

I want to find records that are eliminated by this filter

Yes! I can do this to find those records

```
select count(id)filter(where id<=2 or id>50) from table;
```

But suppose I have complex query I replaced my formula with id in above query for example.

I have a formula that calculates three different times based on different values now if i want to filter each time on some condition I can use filter for example

These are my filters:

```
> start_time<= 40 mins and start_time> 5 mins 

> end_time<= 10 mins and end_time> 1 mins 

> journey_time<= 80 mins and journey_time> 10 mins

> Total_time(start_time+end_time+journey_time) <= 150 and Total_time(start_time+end_time+journey_time) > 15
```

If I want to filter I have to write my formula 8 times (To filter < and >= for each time and total time) This will be my query

```
select 
avg(start_time_formula)filter(where start_time_formula<= 40 and 
start_time_formula>5),
avg(end_time_formula)filter(where end_time_formula<= 10 and         
end_time_formula>1),
avg(journey_time_formula)filter(where journey_time_formula<= 80 and 
journey_time_formula>10)
from table
where (start_time_formula+end_time_formula+journey_time_formula <=150 and 
start_time_formula+end_time_formula+journey_time_formula > 15)
```

Now if I want to find all the discarded values also.

Do I have to write same formula 8 more times that will replace > with <= and "AND" with "OR" so it give me the discarded results or is there any other way to find the discarded values?

**Update**

My table values are

```
id     start_time            end_time         journey_time         Out_time  
 1  2018-04-06 01:37:36 2018-04-06 10:37:36 2018-04-06 04:37:36 2018-04-06 
    11:37:36
 2  2018-04-16 02:37:36 2018-04-16 08:37:36 2018-04-16 06:37:36  2018-04-16 
    07:37:36
 3  2018-05-10 01:37:36 2018-04-10 11:37:36 2018-04-06 09:37:36 2018-04-10 
    10:11:36
 4  2018-05-10 04:37:36 2018-05-10 5:00:36 2018-05-10 04:47:36  2018-05-10 
    05:5:36
```

My Calculations are

> start_time = journey_time - start_time
>
> journey_time = end_time - journey_time
>
> end_time = Out_time - end_time

This is my desired Output

```
start_time           journey_time     end_time   discarded  
 10 mins              13 mins           5 mins      3
```

thanks

Comment: Each filter discards different values.  It is unclear what you really want.

Comment: Yes now I want to get all discarded values discarded by each filter

Comment: . . I think you need to provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

use condition by using case when,so your query would be like below

```
select 
sum(case when start_time_formula <= 40 and start_time_formula>5 then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when end_time_formula<= 10 and end_time_formula>1 then 1 else 0 end) ,
sum(case when where journey_time_formula<= 80 and journey_time_formula>10 then 1 else o end )
from table
where (start_time_formula+end_time_formula+journey_time_formula <=150 and 
start_time_formula+end_time_formula+journey_time_formula > 15)
```

Comment: Ok for example I have to find the count of all the discarded values and also all filtered values how can I get it using case? not using filter?

Comment: case will be fine for that

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner I didn't get it. can you please elaborate it or an example will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Unknown if can share your table values then it will be easy to help you

Comment: I have updated my question with my values and my calculations

Comment: from this output what will be come to your output by using your formula @Unknown

Comment: @Unknown id  ?column?
1  600
2  300
3  -42686
4  280

Comment: @Unknown look this is the sum result of start_time+journey_time+end_time  this time corresponding with id

Comment: Updated my question with formatting.Can you check it now?

Comment: @Unknown your logic realy need more clear to answer your question i tried but fail to got your logic

Comment: No  I have applied my formula on each id but only id#4 fulfills my criteria. that is   start_time<= 40 mins and start_time> 5 mins 
, end_time<= 10 mins and end_time> 1 mins 
, journey_time<= 80 mins and journey_time> 10 mins
, Total_time(start_time+end_time+journey_time) <= 150 and and Total_time(start_time+end_time+journey_time) > 15.So I discarded all other 3 ids and show their count in count and displayed avg of all start_time of NOT discarded value in start_time and avg of all end_time of NOT discarded value in end_time and avg of all journey_time of NOT discarded value in journey_time